# Windows Phone Market 1 App 2 XAPS version 7.8 and 8 is it possible?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

Assume that I am creating an app that I want everyone to be able to enjoy. So I launch a 7.8 version. However, in the 8 version I want to implement 8 only api features. How are you supposed to submit this to the market? Am I supposed to do a single submission with multiple apps? Two separate submissions? Or is this practice not aloud? Please keep the snarky comments to a min. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this blog by  Bernardo Zamora, the Dev center does allow multiple XAP files targeting different versions of the Windows Phone OS.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/15/app-submission-tips-for-windows-phone-7-and-windows-phone-8.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was asking. Thanks